# How do I access the weights and layers of a pre-existing model using CNTK with C#?

Tags: c#, cntk

Using CNTK and C#, I'd like to create class activation maps (CAM).

My model is a densenet model exported from Keras(Tensorflow backend) in ONNX format and I'm importing this in my Windows C# console app using CNTK. Making a CAM involves getting weights and outputs from layers in the middle of a pretrained model. The documentation and examples don't make this very clear so my question is two fold:

1) How do I obtain the weights from a given layer?

2) How do I build a new model using the layers of the already existing densenet model? For CAM, I'd like to use the input of the existing model and the output of the global average pooling layer of the same model (but keeping all the layers that exist between the two layers). For example in Python Keras we use this:

```
layer_model_1 = Model(inputs=model.layers[1].layers[0].input, outputs = model.layers[1].layers[-2].output)
```

Comment: Have you seen this example? https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/tree/master/Examples/Image/TransferLearning

Comment: @snowflake um the link points to python examples. My query is with respect to the c# implementation of cntk. While I have downloaded and gone through examples of c# cntk code on their github, it still wasn't able to answer my question.

Comment: There should be an equivalent api for the C# implementation. Also, the python api tends to be more mature than the C# one, you should consider using python api if possible.